# AutoHotKey - Multiply variables not working

Tags: autohotkey

I have problems with an AutoHotKey script. When I press F1, the left mouse button is held but A is also pressed. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey, 2
Toggle := 0
Toggle2 := 0

F1::
Toggle := !Toggle
If (Toggle){
   Click, Down
} else {
   Click, Up
}

F2::
Toggle2 := !Toggle2
If (Toggle2){
   send {a down}
} else {
   send {a up}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell autohotkey that you are done writing the code that should be executed when a hotkey is pressed by putting a [`Return`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Return.htm) after the last part you want to execute.

From the [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Return.htm):

> Returns from a subroutine to which execution had previously jumped via
> function-call, Gosub, ***Hotkey activation***, GroupActivate, or other
> means.

---

So for your script:

```
#MaxThreadsPerHotkey, 2
Toggle := 0
Toggle2 := 0

F1::
Toggle := !Toggle
If (Toggle){
   Click, Down
} else {
   Click, Up
}
return

F2::
Toggle2 := !Toggle2
If (Toggle2){
   send {a down}
} else {
   send {a up}
}
return
```